# Flutter tabbar screen is not updated

Tags: flutter, indexing, controller, screen, tabbar

I create a method for changing Tabbar. When I run this function, sometimes it's view is changing, sometimes it is not. But every time index is changing successfully. And run full function smoothly. Here is my function

```
class ScreenController extends GetxController with GetTickerProviderStateMixin {
.....

  TabController? profileTabController;
  int profileInitialIndex = 0;
  int profileCurrentIndex = 0;

@override
  onInit() {
    // AppConfig.getVersionStatus();
    profileTabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: profileInitialIndex,
    );
   
    super.onInit();
  }

  //<============================ Change Profile Tabbar
  void changeProfileTabbar(int index) async {
    print("Change Profile Tab 1: $index");

    profileTabController!.index = index >= 0 && index < 3 ? index : 0;
    print("Change Profile Tab 2: ${profileTabController!.index}");
    profileCurrentIndex = index >= 0 && index < 3 ? index : 0;
    print("Change Profile Tab 3: $profileCurrentIndex");
    update();
  }

}
```

Where is the problem ? Why is not the screen updated sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this issue, you can use the animateTo method of the TabController to change the index with animation**

Code:

```
class ScreenController extends GetxController with GetTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? profileTabController;
  int profileInitialIndex = 0;
  int profileCurrentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    profileTabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: profileInitialIndex,
    );
    super.onInit();
  }

  void changeProfileTabbar(int index) async {
    print("Change Profile Tab 1: $index");

    // animate to the new index instead of setting it directly
    profileTabController!.animateTo(
      index >= 0 && index < 3 ? index : 0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );

    print("Change Profile Tab 2: ${profileTabController!.index}");
    profileCurrentIndex = index >= 0 && index < 3 ? index : 0;
    print("Change Profile Tab 3: $profileCurrentIndex");
  }
}
```